# An XTS penguin?

Tags: distinguisher, xts

I stumbled across a [VPN website](https://vikingvpn.com/blogs/security/visualizing-weak-encryption-experiments-with-aes) when looking up information about XTS, and came across their own explanation of different block modes (basically the ECB penguin, but with their company logo instead). What stood out to me was their XTS example, where their logo still shows through:

[image: XTS]

It clearly is visible here. However, [as far as I am aware](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/comments/xts/xts_comments-liskov_minematsu.pdf), a distinguishing attack on XTS implies a distinguishing attack on the underlying cipher. Given their rather simplistic (or inaccurate) descriptions of other block modes, I would not be surprised if they made a mistake in their testing procedure. They claimed all of the images they provided were created using the `openssl` utility.

**How could they possibly have come up with this bitmap using XTS?**

---

XTS is a tweakable narrow-block cipher mode with ciphertext stealing. Ignoring the ciphertext stealing (which makes it functionally equivalent to XEX with two keys), the block mode is defined as

\begin{align}
T &= E_{K_2}(i) \otimes \alpha^j\\
C &= E_{K_1}(P \oplus T) \oplus T
\end{align}

where $K_2$ is the tweak key, $K_1$ is the main key, $i$ is the sector number, $j$ is the block number, and $\alpha$ is the primitive element of $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$ defined by polynomial $x$, i.e. the number 2. $\otimes$ is modular multiplication of two polynomials over the binary field $\operatorname{GF}(2)$, modulo $x^{128} + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1$.

Things can go wrong if $j = 0$ (in XEX) or if the same $i$ is re-used for multiple sectors.

Comment: I suspect that they may have misused XTS, possibly by treating each block as a separate plaintext, and encrypting them all with the same $i$ (rather than using different $i$'s, or encrypting the entire thing as a large plaintext)

Comment: They claim to have shared their methodology.  Have you tried (fixing the bugs in their invocations of `openssl` and) reproducing their results?  If not, try it and report back!

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage They didn't mention exactly how they used `openssl`, only for their sample with CBC. The other mods can have different options.

Comment: @forest What happens if you replace CBC by XTS in that `openssl enc` invocation?  (You may also need to insert hyphens: `openssl enc -aes-128-xts ...`.)

Comment: Tried to at least. Only system with `openssl` right now is a shell server that just went down. Perhaps later today I'll be back on my real *nix machine.

Comment: OpenSSL can be installed on Windows as well, it is I think in the Ubuntu system that is available on enterprise versions and it is of course present in CygWin if you install it - which as a tweaker you should :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the Windows Subsystem for Linux is available on all Windows editions (and offers Kali, Ubuntu, Suse and Debian IIRC).

Comment: Who said I was on Winblows?

Comment: Last OpenSSL I checked says: _Ciphers in XTS mode are not supported by the enc utility_

Comment: $\alpha$ is not really ‘the number 2’; rather if you write down, as a sequence of bits, the coefficients highest-degree-first of the canonical polynomial of an element of $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$ modulo $p = x^{128} + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1$, then the polynomial $x = 0 x^7 + \cdots + 0 x^2 + 1 x + 0$ can be written as 00000010.  $\alpha$ is the equivalence class of $x$, or the coset $x + (p)$ where $(p)$ is the ideal generated by $p$ in $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$.  This bit string 00000010 happens to be the big-endian bit representation of the number 2, but that's where the resemblance ends.

Comment: @fgrieu With an older version of OpenSSL, `openssl enc -aes-256-xts` used to produce output.  It starts with the bytes `Salted__` and an additional sixteen bytes apparently chosen at random, so I have no idea what it is supposed to _mean_ and what it interoperates with, but it _runs_!  Maybe that's what they used.